# How can I draw an image on a canvas element through jquery? Or do I have to use javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, draw

I need to know how I can draw an image on a canvas element, through JQuery. I really wanted to use JQuery because it's much simpler and I know more about it that pure javascript, although I will use javascript if i have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no jQuery functionality specific to canvas. There are other libraries that abstract that, though, such as [canto](http://code.google.com/p/canto-js/), [artisanjs](http://www.artisanjs.com/), [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/), [easel.js](http://easeljs.com/), [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/), [gury.js](https://github.com/rsandor/gury).

I usually begin with familiarizing myself with the basics, though, before I use someone else's API. The canvas API is pretty chatty, but it's not difficult to use. Here's a good [tutorial on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/

you might find some useful info here :)

and an example of what it does can be found here:
http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/649/example5.html

this can be combined with jquery. but mostly is just native javascript I believe